# How to force the columns to stack before resize with bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

**Context**

I'm making a responsive mosaic and I decided to go with tables since I can control how they stack on smaller screens.

May be that´s not the best way but so far it is working.

**Problem**

Below is the code, which is basically two columns and within each column, a table. They are displayed ok, however when I resize the screen until the first breakpoint, it resizes and the second column of the first table goes behind the first column of the second table, as shown in the picture. It happens once or twice more before stacking both tables.

[image]

***HTML***

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm nopadding" style="background-color: #6EBCD2;">
            <img src="img/Cubierta_recetas.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm nopadding" style="background-color: #EEDF4B;">
            <img src="img/Cubierta_foncep.png">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

***CSS***

```
.table td, .table th {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

You can see it here
https://jsfiddle.net/envm6920/1/

**What I want?**

I want them stacked since the first breakpoint.

**UPDATE**
As there is much more code than needed I simplify the things so people don´t get distracted by irrelevant code.
In detail, I eliminated the table.

Use images 254x254, but I guess that is not relevant either.

Comment: CSS Grid is probably a much better option here than tables.

Comment: I appreciate that comment but des not lead me anywhere. If you remove the table, the resizing stil happens and I want it to stack

Comment: Is there a specific range of screen widths where the problem is evident. I'm yet to replicate the issue in your fiddle.

Comment: I just updated the code and the fiddler link. just resize the output window and you´ll see thet at the first breakpoints, before stacking, there is a resizing of the columns width. That´s what I would like it not to happen. stack at the first breakpoint

Comment: looks like changin col-md by col-xxl or col-xl does the trick. But I really don´t understand why.